# Dealing with MITM attack in e-voting systems

Tags: cryptanalysis, homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption, man-in-the-middle

I've read many e-voting papers that use El-Gamal scheme which I recall is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack, yet I find no discussion or even mentioning of it in those papers.

-Does anyone knows why?
-Is it completely solved or dealt with?

-I only found this old paper about it
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Securing-e-voting-against-MITM-attacks-Mitropoulos-Spinellis/d1acfa22dbad93a3034ca2593da2b6e146246f1b#citing-papers

The paper uses simple human machine interaction test; in their conclusion:

> the idea that during electronic elections,
> a Turing test can be utilized to determine whether a vote is
> cast by a human or by malicious software. An advantage of
> our proposal is that it does not require specialized hardware
> or a physical secondary channel, thus making it suitable for
> large-scale elections. Our scheme as such ***does not provide user anonymity***, because in the form we described it, its authentication is based on a TAN. Hence, the e-voting system that will benefit from our scheme must provide another layer
> that will deal with the separation of the users’ authentication details from their vote and the provision of an appropriate auditing infrastructure. Finally, usability issues must be taken into account since CAPTCHAs are not the most efficient solutions especially for the elderly.

-Isn't this necessitates a discussion of this extra layer??
especially all this sophisticated Homomorphic Encryption is used to verify with privacy (to avoid coercion or vote selling)
.
Recent example papers:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-43756-4_2

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-43756-4_5

-Another question that I'm not sure should I added here or as a separate one:
The nature of the e-voting problem imply *the possession of many plain-cipher pairs, before-after shuffle pairs, and also maybe controlling the entrance order* (like front/back running or sandwiching in DeFi) by competing entities, are there any ***cryptanalysis work*** on this (like deferential attacks or something)?

Thanks,

Comment: For convenience, here is a direct [link](https://www2.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/conf/2009-PCI-MITM/html/MS09b.pdf) to the first paper. That I post this link shall not be construed as an endorsement! Though I have at least two positive things to say about that paper: however impractical and imperfectly secure, there's an idea in that article; and the rather strange use of big-endian and little-endian is not a technical error, it's a conscious joke.

Comment: This is a pdf link of the same paper I'm referring to